# On a subset of the associated primes of tensor product of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, flatness, primary-decomposition

For a module $M$ over a commutative ring $R$, let

$\operatorname{Ass}_R (M):=\{\operatorname{ann}_R (m) \mid m\in M$ and $\operatorname{ann}_R(m) \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)\}$.

If $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and $P \in \operatorname{Ass}_R(M)$ and $N$ is a flat $R$-module, then is it true that $\operatorname{Ass}_R(N/PN)\subseteq \operatorname{Ass}_R(M \otimes_R N) $ ?

If $R$ is moreover Noetherian, then how to prove that $Ass(M \otimes N)=\cup_{P \in Ass(M)} Ass(N/PN)$ ?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but what's the context? Why is this plausible, and what thoughts do you have on the question?

Comment: Why you ask a question whose proof is in Bourbaki in greater generality?

Comment: Moreover, the first part is trivial: $0\to R/P\to M$ is exact and tensorizing by $N$ it remains so.